# Comparing 2 csv files and show differences (but not the entire line)

Tags: python, sql, linux, csv, compare

I have to compare *2 relatively large SQL scripts* (~2gb) in bash (using a `docker container`).

Tried CSV-diff & other commands but those show me the entire line where the difference occurs, and some line (the insert) contains millions of characters, so I would like to know if there is a command or a python script that I've missed that allows doing that.

The scripts look like

```
"INSERT INTO 'Table' VALUES (ValueX1,ValueX2...),(ValueY1,ValueY2..)"
```

so I guess it should split with every, or ()

Don't know if it's clear enough but thanks in advance for anyone helping

Comment: *(1)* please supply an example *(2)* millions of characters?!

Comment: Its a script i get when i dump my mysql DB so by millions of characters i mean the lines that insert values in the tables are really really long. As for the example :

Comment: Example INSERT INTO `Table` VALUES (1,'N',NULL,'91','F',2019-08-11 00:00:00',NULL,'2019-02-05 12:00:00',NULL,NULL,'N',NULL,'V','2019-10-04 02:24:07',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),(2,'D',NULL,'81',3,BN,'2019-05-11 00:00:00',NULL,'2019-08-05 11:00:27',NULL,NULL,'N',NULL,'V','2019-11-04 16:00:10',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),(3,'H',NULL,'JK1',74,F,'2019-12-19 00:00:00',NULL,'2019-09-25 00:30:00',NULL,NULL,'N',NULL,'V','2019-11-04 16:47:07',NULL,NULL,NULL) so ideally it would compare each data set

Answer (score 1):

> I guess it should split with every, …

Yes, you can do exactly this - to only see the differences between e. g. commas, you can split the input there:

```
diff <(<script1 tr , \\n) <(<script2 tr , \\n)
```

Comment: Trying this but the process lasts forever

Comment: How long exactly was _forever_?

Comment: Cant tell but it got killed each time i tried to use a diff

Comment: _it got killed_ by whom?

Comment: it got automatically stopped and i dont find any log

Comment: Maybe there's not enough (virtual) memory available and the [OOM killer](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/dev-oom-killer.html) is enabled. You could also try whether `diff --speed-large-files` makes a difference.